# Is there any way to put dynamic list of data in html email template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend

Assume I had a site that are sending emails to its user with the cart contents that are added by the users dynamically, all users have different data.
How can I achieve this, since email html template does not support script inside it.

Comment: Can you please add your code? We can't resolve any issues without any code to inspect.

Comment: Simply, I am fetching the product list from database(which is different for every user) and then how can I add them to html email template.

Comment: Do you want to update an already sent email with the latest added products in the cart?

Comment: No, I want to send email which contains the list of products that the user is purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which takes product data as input and generates the html template

```
Something like: 
     function generateHTMLTemplate (product){
              return `<div class='name-style'>${product.name}</div>`
        }
```

Comment: But I have dynamic list(means its size is not fixed )and it is different for different user

Comment: the concept will remain same. for e.g. list.map(item=>`<div class='list-item'>${item.name}</div>` ) The idea is to identify the pattern and generate it's equivalent template.

Comment: demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g4qaps9w/

Comment: is script allowed inside the mail content

Comment: you'll be sending the mail through some kind of script right?

Comment: Yes, I am sending the mail from the backend using the Node Js . but tell me how can i pass the list from node Js file to html file(which contains the email template)